# Confusion of local Lp spaces for finite measures

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a finite measure space.  Then are there any functions which are any functions which are locally integrable but not integrable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X=\mathbb N$ with  the power set as  the sigma algebra. Let $\mu(\{n\})=\frac  1 {2^{n}}$. Then **any** real valued function is measurable and locally integrable. The function $f(n)=2^{n}$ for all $n$ is not integrable.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X=\mathbb{R}$, $\Sigma$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$, and let $\mu$ be dominated by the Lebesgue measure with Radon-Nikodym derivative $e^{-|x|}$.  Then the function
$$
f(x)= e^{x^2} \in L^1_{loc,\mu} - L^1.
$$